# Adding info from parentdatatable to column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I'm trying to display in column info from parent dataTable:

```
Country (Id int, Name nvarchar)
State (Id int, Name nvarchar, CountryId)
Province (Id int, Name nvarchar,StateId)
City (Id int, Name nvarchar,ProvinceId)
```

Now I can display `name of province + name of state`, but I also want to display and sort by `nameOfCountry`

There is a first problem:
There is no such column in `EnumProvince dataTable`

```
dictionaryData.EnumProvince.DefaultView.Sort = dictionaryData.EnumProvince.EnumStateIdColumn.ColumnName + "," + dictionaryData.EnumState.EnumCountryIDColumn.ColumnName ;
for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryData.EnumProvince.DefaultView.Count; i++)
{
    DictionaryData.EnumProvinceRow row1 = ((DictionaryData.EnumProvinceRow)dictionaryData.EnumProvince.DefaultView[i].Row);
    DataRow row2 = dataTable2.NewRow();
    row2[0] = row1.EnumProvinceID;
    //There is a second problem: row2 hasn't EnumCountryRow.
    row2[1] = row1.Name + "(" + row1.EnumStateRow.Name +" - " + row1.EnumCountryRow.Name + ")";
    dataTable2.Rows.Add(row2);
}

    (dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[2] as RemindableDataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dataTable2;
    (dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[2] as RemindableDataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = dataTable2.Columns[1].ColumnName;
    (dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[2] as RemindableDataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = dataTable2.Columns[0].ColumnName;
     dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "EnumProvinceId";
```

Is there any simple way to add this feature to this grid ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution but is very ugly :/

```
row2[1] = row1.Name + opis + "(" + row1.EnumStateRow.Name + " - " + row1.EnumStateRow.Name ;
                            for (int indexOfCountry = 0; indexOfCountry < dictionaryData.EnumCountry.DefaultView.Count; indexOfCountry++)
                            {
                                var sth = ((DictionaryData.EnumCountryRow)dictionaryData.EnumCountry.DefaultView[indexOfCountry].Row);
                                if(sth.EnumCountryID==row1.EnumStateRow.EnumCountryID)
                                {
                                    row2[1] += " - " + sth.Name + ")";
                                }
                            }
```